# Configure iPlanet to redirect to a single server from multiple servers

Tags: webserver, iplanet

I have a web application ( `A` )that runs on 3 Weblogic Instances and a web application ( `B` )that runs on 1 of those 8 Weblogic instances.

I want a link from Application `A` to redirect to Application `B`, regardless of which `Server` Weblogic it is coming from.

Server 1 has application `A` and application `B`, servers 2 and 3 only have Application `A`.

right now it does this ( where the # is the number of the server ):

```
A1 -> B1
A2 -> B2
A3 -> B3
```

I want it to do this:

```
A1 -> B1
A2 -> B1
A3 -> B1
```

How do I configure the `obj.conf` to accomplish this?

Comment: `iplanet`? What does `iplanet` have to do with this?

Comment: I need to configure iPlanet to do this, what part of *"How do I configure the `obj.conf` to accomplish this?"* isn't clear?

Comment: The part where you then mention 11 Weblogic servers, and enumerate them. And then don't mention any iplanet servers. Are you trying to configure a reverse proxy? Are you trying to send a HTTP redirect? Did you know this is the only question on SO that's tagged with IPlanet? I realize Oracle still ships something with the name, but the Sun/Netscape alliance is as dead as those two companies.